# Sonarcloud analysis report capture in the azure pipeline

Tags: email, azure-pipelines-yaml, sonarcloud

I need to send an email after run the sonaranalysis@1 in azure pipeline then we will get sonarcloud link with PR ID(logs). I have prepared the send email task but I need sonarcloud link genated task can any one help..!
#Without hard coded of sonarcloud link

Thanks,
Nagarjuna

SonarCloudLink="https://sonarcloud.io/summary/new_code?id=$projectkey &$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)"